# Does the size of the signature on the passport matter?

Tags: passports

I have never had a signature so I made one and practised it over and over to make sure it looked same or if not similar but when I did it on the passport it enbed up being really small does this matter?

Comment: What country issued the passport?. Is the signature written in the Roman alphabet (like the letters used in travel stack exchange) or some other system (Chinese, Arabic, etc.)?

Comment: More importantly, is it easy to falsify because it is so small (where I am assuming you mean short)?

Comment: @MarkJohnson usages for signatures vary greatly. In the US, a signature is rarely any different from the person just writing their full name, so it’s wide an not very tall, like the space provided for that on the back of credit cards. In other countries, a signature is a lot more “artistic”, and differs greatly from just writing your name (sometimes it’s really completely unrelated), and it has a tendency to be somewhat more “square”. Trying to fit one on a space designed for the other will often lead to it becoming very small.

Comment: @jcaron I am aware of that. My comment is asking for clarification if in the OP case he is using a form of abbriviation, that is sometimes used in work places. In my case the first 2 letters 'Jo' instead of the full name. That would not be a legal signature. Thus the comments as to whether the OP really means 'short' instead of 'small' .

Comment: @jcaron Or to state this otherwise: A signature based on  **initials** would not be a legal signature.

Answer (score 3):

I have had passports since I was a kid, been to many countries and being a crewmember you can imagine how much my passports have been used and how many immigration officers have seen it.

With all of that, I have never signed my passport, even though there is a space to do so. No one ever asked me why, not in the US nor Europe, not in the far or middle east.

However, a signature is a personal choice, being small or big does not mean it's bad or good. If you ever been asked, just say this is how you do it. Size does not matter in this specific case (unlike other things).

Comment: In Germany, a signature on a ID card (or passport) is  used a varifiable signature for contracts (the signature is done in the presence of an official). So with an unsigned (foreign) passport you cannot sign a legal contract.